# Variable from conditional statement

Tags: bash, variables, conditional-statements

I have a few scripts I am taking ownership of that use Bash shell, there is a find statement inside a conditional statement.

Something like this:

```
if [ -z $(find / -type f -perm -002) ] ; then echo "no world writable found"
```

where as an else I would like to display what was found instead of `world write perms found`.

I can do:

```
echo $(find / -type f -perm -002) has world write permissions
```

or set variable to `$(find / -type f -perm -002)`.

But was wondering if there was a a better way to do this. Is there another way to retrieve the contents of the find statement as a variable?

Comment: What is wrong about assigning the result of the find to a variable?

Comment: `result=$(find / -type f -perm -002)` or `local result=$(find / -type f -perm -002)` if contained in a function would be the idiomatic way.

Comment: Note that in the original, you need to quote the command substitution, because if it expands to more than one word, `[` will complain about too many operands.

Comment: This quite often a long list. Management has emphasized minimal changes as preference. So just exploring the possibility there may be some crazy regex unknown to me that will use what is there to present the content in the find command without making it run again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just take the output and store it in a variable. If it is not empty you can print its contents. This way you only need to run the command once.

```
RESULT=$(find / -type f -perm -002)
if [ -z "$RESULT" ]
then
    echo "no world writable found"
else
    echo "$RESULT has world write permissions"
fi
```

Comment: After looking at it, this does seem to be the most elegant way. I will push back at Mgmt on this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use use [`sed`](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/) to insert a headline, if you like.

```
REPORT=$(find /tmp -type f -perm -002 | sed '1s/^/Found world write permissions:\n/')
echo ${REPORT:-No world writable found.}
```

Notice: your example seems to be broken, because `find` can return more than one line.

And [`awk`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/) can do both at once:

```
find /tmp -type f -perm -002 | 
awk -- '1{print "Found world write permissions:";print};END{if(NR==0)print "No world writable found."}'
```

Comment: This is clever. I learned something here. Thanks for your response!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind not having the message `no world writable found`, you can use a single `find` statement, and that's all:

```
find / -type f -perm -002 -printf '%p has world write permissions\n'
```

---

If you need to store the returned files for future use, store them in an array (assuming Bash):

```
#!/bin/bash

files=()

while IFS= read -r -d '' f; do
    files+=( "$f" )
    # You may also print the message:
    printf '%s has world write permissions\n' "$f"
done < <(find / -type f -perm -002 -print0)

# At this point, you have all the found files
# You may print a message if no files were found:

if ((${#files[@]}==0)); then
    printf 'No world writable files found\n'
    exit 0
fi

# Here you can do some processing with the files found...
```

Comment: Would the raging downvoter care explain his/her act?